# IIS server short name

Tags: iis

On my **IIS** server, I found a problem.

If I create a file with the name `a~a.html` it's okay and the file can be accessed like this:

```
http://localhost/a~a.html
```

but if I create a file with the name: `a~1.html`, every time I access `http://localhost/a~1.html` it always returns a `404` error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Now, I know this problem is related to the **IIS** short file name.

Answer (score 1):

It works normally on my side, a~1.html is your file name, it has nothing to do with IIS short file name.

[image]

You can try to clear your cache or check if there is url rewrite in your website. these reasons may cause 404 errors.